# Doxygen \code blockdo

Tags: doxygen, markup

I'm updating some Doxygen documentation, and when Doxygen generates the code blocks for the documentation, it no longer puts the code in a block when it's surrounded by the `\code` and `\endcode` tags.

Original:
[image: Original Doxygen, with code blocks]

New:
[image: New Doxygen, no code blocks]

The documentation was originally generated with 1.6.1, and the new documentation is using 1.8.1.2.  Since the versions are different, do I now have to use the [markdown](http://www.doxygen.nl/markdown.html) syntax to generate the proper code blocks, or can I continue to use the `\code` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `\code..\endcode` still works as always.

What is like the problem is that you use a custom page header or stylesheet (i.e. `HTML_STYLESHEET` or `HTML_HEADER` is not empty in the config file) and the newer version of doxygen started using different CSS tags to style the code block, and these are missing from your stylesheet.

Doxygen recently introduced a `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` option which you can use to overrule parts of the original stylesheet. I recommend to use that option instead of `HTML_STYLESHEET`.

Comment: Yeah, that was it.  `HTML_STYLESHEET` wasn't empty, so I just changed that to `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` and it worked.